# How to change the working directory in C?

Tags: c, linux, chdir

`chdir` can be used for constant character paths (it takes a `const char *`), but not for paths inputted by the user (since they have type `char *`). Is there any way around this?

Comment: What is the problem with using chdir()? It sure can be used with paths provided by the user... Did you try it? Have it failed? How? Post some code...

Comment: Further to Roman's answer: in general, a `const` qualifier on a function parameter means the function won't attempt to modify what you pass, so it *can* be a string constant, not that it *has* to be a constant. In `T const *` (for whatever type T), the `const` basically means "read-only".

Answer (score 8):

`chdir` can be used with arbitrary string. `const` modifier means that it will not modify your string.

Answer (score 1):

To expand on [Roman Cheplyaka's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3662627/how-to-change-the-working-directory-in-c/3662644#3662644), type qualifiers can always be *added* to pointer types, but not removed.  This means that a function that takes a `const char *` parameter is really saying it can take either a `char *` *or* a `const char *` (which effectively means it is promising not to alter the contents of the string).

Similarly, a function that has a `volatile char *` parameter can take either a `char *` or a `volatile char *` as the actual argument, and a function that takes a `const volatile char *` parameter can take any of `char *`, `const char *`, `volatile char *`, or `const volatile char *`.