# Is that command valid in C?

Tags: c, linux, bash, shell, directory

I want to change directory in unix using code in a C file.I tried this:

```
 char command[50];
 strcpy( command, "cd newdirectory/" );
 system(command);
```

but it didn't work.Other commands using "system" work.

Comment: your command would work, but only within the `system()` call. i.e. if you do `system("cd newdirectory && rm foo");`, `rm foo` will happen in `newdirectory`.

Comment: @zmo that was the problem.i didn't know that it could execute the command but remain in the current directory.you can make it an answer(correct)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

your command would work, but only within the `system()` call. *e.g.*: if you do `system("cd newdirectory && rm foo");`, `rm foo` will happen in `newdirectory`.

That's because the `system()` call does an `fork()` where you change the environment, but when it gets back to your calling program, you get back to your original environment.

To change the directory of your current process, you have to follow user1929959's answer: *i.e.* usinc the `chdir()` system call.

Comment: This is missing a critical element. system forks a subprocess, and then it's the subprocess that execs the shell and runs the cd command. Because this happens in a subprocess, it affects the environment of the subprocess, but never even touches the environment of the calling process. It doesn't "get back" to the original environment, the calling process never left it.

Comment: cf [man page](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/system.html), you're right, it is indeed a `fork()`.

Answer (score 7):

To change directory try to use [chdir](http://linux.die.net/man/3/chdir). A related question is [How to change the working directory in C?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3662627/how-to-change-the-working-directory-in-c). About using system see [Why can't we change directories through system() system call in Linux?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14257245/why-cant-we-change-directories-through-system-system-call-in-linux) and [Changing the current directory in Linux using C++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3747014/changing-the-current-directory-in-linux-using-c).